# PHP file not running on local host

Tags: php, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Book A Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Book A Table</h1>



<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $numErr=$dateErr = $timeErr = personsErr="";
$name = $email = $num= $date = $time = $persons = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["num"])) {
     $numErr = "Number is required";
   } else {
     $num = test_input($_POST["num"]);
   }



   if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
     $dateErr = "Date is required";
   } else {
     $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
   }



   if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
     $timeErr = "Time is required";
   } else {
     $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["persons"])) {
     $personsErr = "Number of persons is required";
   } else {
     $persons = test_input($_POST["persons"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Full Name<br> <input type="text" name="name">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail<br> <input type="text" name="email">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Contact Number <input type="text" name="num">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $numErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Reservation Date*<br> <input type="date" name="date"><br><br>
   <span class="error"><?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Reservation Time*<br>(Mon - Thur: 18:00 - 23:00 Fri - Sun: 12:00 - 00:00)<br> <input type="time" name="time"><br><br>
<span class="error"><?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Number of Persons*<br> <input type="text" name="persons"><br><br>
<span class="error"><?php echo $personsErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Comments<br><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php

echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $num;
echo "<br>";
echo $date;
echo "<br>";
echo $time;
echo "<br>";
echo $persons;
echo "<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

> I just started learning PHP today so im a beginner and im not very
>   familiar with it. trying to use php on a local host to make a booking
>   reservation page for a restaurant. What i was trying to do is make a
>   form and validate it so that the user wont be able to leave out any
>   required fields. however it doesnt seem to work.  can anyone tell me
>   where i went wrong please ?

Comment: "personsErr" is not declared as a variable. Get yourself some PHP IDE and enable error reporting in your PHP, otherwise you'll keep running into this typo issues.

Comment: thankyou ! and will do

Answer (score 0):

if there aren't any errors you have to check the name of the php file? does it have the extension ".php"?
Are you referring the right directory?
is the server running?